# jQuery: selector for button inside a form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, event-handling, submit

I'm having trouble selecting an element inside a form. The code looks like this:

```
    <div id="form"> 
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input id="txt_name" type="text" name="search" value="" />        
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
    </div>
```

and I need to handle click/submit event on the button, using jquery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(":submit").click(function () { /*some scripting here*/
```

The problem is that the click event gets completely ignored but when I put the button element outside the form, it works just fine. It seems I'm not using the jquery selector correctly or something.
Also I can't just put the button outside the form since the post method is being handled by server side C# script and runs database access.

Comment: Can you add an ID to the button and use that instead? e.g. 

`<button id="submit_button" type="submit">Search</button>`

and

`$('#submit_button').click(function () { /*some scripting here*/`

Comment: You can actually use the $().submit() event as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'submit' event ([jQuery Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)). Give your form an ID and select the form, or simply select it how it is now.

```
//added an id of ='form-id' to the form
$('#form-id').submit(function(){

});

//as it is currently
$('#form form').submit(function(){

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5kuu/)

Comment: I tried exactly this before and now again. It just doesn't work even though it should.

Comment: Added a demo to my answer, take a look.

Comment: this looks promising, it works the same way as jqueryrocks mentioned with this selector: $('div#form form').submit(function() { }); So the data printed by script dissapear.

Comment: Well you're using a form, so it will follow the natural behavior, which is submitting to the target page. If you want to prevent the form from submitting (maybe if you're submitting the form via ajax) you could prevent the default action of the form, using **preventDefault**.

Comment: This is almost it, now the data from script persist on page, but the problem is the form doesn't post...so my server script won't run.

Comment: Right. If you want to remain on the same page, you will have to submit your form manually via ajax. You can create an AJAX POST request with $.ajax(), sending the form variables to your processing page behind the scenes. Google it!

Comment: I'm gonna try that, time to learn ajax i guess :) Thank you very much for help. I'm finally getting somewhere after 2 days struggle.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to give your `button` an `id` and say something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#idOfSubmitButton").click(function () { /*some scripting here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#form form').submit(function() { });
```

Comment: this solution looks like the right one, there is just one problem - after the script runs and prints some data, it dissapears again in less than a second.